# Верно ли расставлены знаки препинания: нужна ли запятая перед "и в колени бьёт земля"?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, однородные-неоднородные-определения

Но сил хва­та­ет лишь на то, что­бы приб­ли­зить­ся к мес­ту каз­ни — там ее но­ги под­ка­шива­ют­ся, и в ко­лени бь­ёт зем­ля; дол­жно быть, смерть уже сов­сем близ­ка, по­тому что гас­ну­щее соз­на­ние ри­су­ет не­во­об­ра­зимую кар­ти­ну: ей ме­рещит­ся, буд­то на од­ну из сто­роже­вых ба­шен с не­ба опус­ка­ет­ся кры­латое чу­дови­ще.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

.***..там ее ноги подкашиваются и в колени бьёт земля;***

Запятая перед И не ставится,  так как ***там*** — это общее наречие для этих двух предложений в составе сложной конструкции. Предложения читаются в одну фразу, союз И соединяет их.

Остальные знаки расставлены верно.